# How to add Dashcode output in PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, copy, dashcode

How can I add Dashcode project HTML content to a PhoneGap project?

A straight copy the of the Dashcode project's html file contents to the www folder results in a blank white screen displayed in the iOS simulator. Do I need to modify the index.html?

The www folder listing after copying the Dashcode html project contents:

```
/Images/
/Parts/
/mobile/
/safari/
index.html
sampleData.js
phonegap-1.4.0.js
```

Thanks in advance,
-Ed

Answer (score 0):

I found the following wiki that may be useful:
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494775/Getting%20started%20with%20Dashcode